# Ehcache RMI replication in springboot not working both way

Tags: ehcache

I am using ehcache 2.6.8 and running on spring 1.5. Below is the my ehcache xml. I have two nodes where the code is deployed in tomcat server in linux box.

Below is the ehcache.xml that i am using in my application.

```
<ehcache name="ehCacheConfig">

  <!--disk location where cache will be stored; currently default tmp file path   -->
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <!-- cache manager peer provider -->
    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1, multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=32" />
    <!-- cache manager peer Listener -->
    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" 
        properties="port=40001"/>

    <cache
        name="EmpCache"
        maxBytesLocalHeap="150M"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
        timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        statistics="true"   >
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true,
        replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true "/>
    </cache> 
</ehcache>
```

Issue: The data is replicating from node 1 to node 2. But when any request is comes in node 2 and data is cache, then it is not getting replicated in node 1, Can some one let me know if I am missing anything?

Comment: It is solved, the issue was due to wrong entry in the host files of node1, where the domain name of node1 was mapped to 127.0.0.1 IP. After removing this wrong entry it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, the issue was due to wrong entry in the host files of node1, where the domain name of node1 was mapped to 127.0.0.1 IP. After removing this wrong entry it worked.